# Are there still many refugees on the Copenhagen-Hamburg train?

Tags: trains, event-based-effects, copenhagen, hamburg

Last time I traveled with DB/DSB (DeutscheBahn - German Trains) by train between these two cities there were groups of people who did not have passports and created a lot of problems in both directions both in first class and second class in the train. Can someone tell me what the situation is now?

Comment: *From news reports*, the situation is less crowded right now, but that could change on short notice. The cold weather spell reduced refugee movements.

Comment: @Eva Please can you indicate the last time you travelled with DB?

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing that you traveled with Deutsche Bahn on this train in 2015.

We can gather from various news reports that while the refugee crisis is not over, the situation has started to improve - I feel it is unlikely that you would have problems described on the question on a particularly big scale.

News articles show that Deutsche Bahn have been doing projects to try and solve such problems [like here](http://www.railwaygazette.com/news/single-view/view/db-launches-training-programme-for-refugees.html) and [here](http://www.deutschebahn.com/en/group/im_blickpunkt/10042376/20150909_refugees.html)

If we were to suddenly hear of the situation worsening, you might want to re-assess the situation, but you will probably be fine in present times